# Observability matrix different forms

Tags: control-system, math, matrix, state-space

The observability matrix formula is present in two forms in textbooks. My question is about which one to use.

the first one:

[image: Qo=[trans(C) trans(A)*trans(C) .......]

the second one:

[image: Qo=[]

Now when applying both on the same system, I get different results:

[image]

first formula:

[image]

second formula:

[image]

edit:i need the observability matrix to preform transformation of the state space equation to a Observable canonical form

Comment: The two formulas and your two results differ only in the fact the they are tranposed with respect to one another. You'll have to look at how the inputs were defined in each case.

Comment: You might have more luck at math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the observable canonical form, you need to use the second formula. If the state for the observable canonical form are z, they are the related to the original ones x by z = (observablity matrix). x

The following are the results from Mathematica.

[image]